# how to execute action methods of a component from a controller or router in ember

Tags: ember.js

I need assistance in executing action methods defined in ember components from outside. (even though ember follows DATA Down and Actions Up approach). My usecase is as follows

```
Application Template

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="application">
       <h2> Dialog Component </h2>
       {{outlet}}
    </script>

Index Template
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="index">
        <button {{action "showDialog1"}}>Open Dialog 1</button>
        <button {{action "showDialog2"}}>Open Dialog 2</button>
        {{#if openFirst}}
           {{#modal-dialog  name="dlg1" title="Modal 1" auto-open="true" onOpen=(action "handleDialogOpen" "dlg1") }} Content of the Dialog ...{{/modal-dialog}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#modal-dialog name="dlg2" title="Modal 2" onOpen=(action "handleDialogOpen" "dlg2")}} Content of the dialog ... {{/modal-dialog}}
    </script>

Modal Dialog Template
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="components/modal-dialog">
        <div class="titlebar-title">
           <span> {{title}} </span>
           <a class="closeBtn" {{action "close"}}>X</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
         {{yield}}
        </div>
    </script>

Index Controller

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
      openFirst : false,
      actions : {
         showDialog1 : function(){
            this.toggleProperty("openFirst");  // open and close the first dialog when clicking the button.
         },
         showDialog2 : function(){
            // want to trigger "open" action of modal-dialog component without using any conditionals(if-else) and without observing "auto-open" attribute
            ......

         },
         handleDialogOpen : function(dialogName){
            if(dialogName === "dlg1"){
               // do something.
            }else if(dialogName === "dlg2"){
               // do something
            }
         }
      }
});

Modal Dialog Component

App.ModalDialogComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
        tagName : 'div',
        classNames : ['ui-dialog'],
        attributeNames : ['title','name','auto-open'],
        didInsertElement : function(){
             if(this.get("auto-open")){
                this.send("open");
             }
        },
        actions : {
              open : function(){
                 $(this.element).show();
                 this.onOpen()
              },
              close : function(){
                  $(this.element).hide();
              }
        }
});

Css Style Definition

ui-dialog{
  display : none;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing actions from controller inside component it not recommended approach. Why does your modal send Save and Cancel actions to the controller and router instead.

Ember has sendAction which you use to send action from component to controller or router.

Inside component you can define an action like this Ember 1.x

```
{{my-component action="doSomething"}}
```

which you can send to controller in router

```
MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function() {
   this.sendAction();
  }
});
```

This will trigger doSomething from component to controller. In ember 2.x  you can check them here, they are pretty much the same

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/handling-events#toc_sending-actions

Lets say that you want to open modal. Inside component you would define a property called isOpen that will show hide modal content

```
{{my-modal isOpen=isOpen}}
```

There is a prop on controller that also has this field which you pass from controller to component. Inside your template you could say:

```
{{#if isOpen}}
  {{my-modal ....this will trigger didInertElement on component that you can use to handle backdrop ...etc
{{/if}}
```

App Labs has a great example on how to do the modals which integrates with ember-cli

https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog

Comment: Thank You so much @Mirza Memic. I will take a look at ember-modal-dialog.

Comment: If we use conditionals, every time components are attached and detached from the DOM. Does it affect any performance ? (because DOM Manipulation is  heavy)

Comment: No I do not think so. Ember from 1.13 is using Glimmer which is very  optimized. I have done a lot of heavy operations and performance was not an issue.